# jQuery offset cuts off top of page

Tags: jquery, html, css

So i am working on this website and when i try to add this piece of code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery('#gedichten').offset().top -200}, 'slow');
});
```

When you fill in the form it refreshes the page and should scroll to the assigned DIV however it adds 200 white pixels on the bottom of the page and cuts off about 200 on the top of the page so the header gets cut off.

[Link to how the header should look](https://sinterklaas.fm/gedichtenmaker/)

Is there any logical explaination for this issue since i cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: can you provide the code check out the issue.

Comment: I have added the code in the original post or what other code do you need?

Comment: Add a snippet containing just enough code to demonstrate the problem